# How to do a query on a column containing comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have 2 tables

table1

```
    id      username      category

    1       nick          1, 2
```

table2

```
    id      category
    1        friend
    2        enemy
    3        neutral
```

now i want to print a list of  just the categories with the id that does NOT appear in the table1 category list of coma separated values. for example in this case 'neutral'. Would appreciate the help i'm out of ideeas.

Comment: -1 "write this query for me"

Comment: If at all possible, normalize your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    table2 b 
        LEFT JOIN table1 a
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.ID, a.category)
WHERE   a.category IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a38/1)

Consider normalizing your table properly. Saving comma separated value in a single column is a bad idea. Problems will arise soon if you have larger database. Here's my proposed Schema:

**Table1 - UserList**

- **UserID (PK)**
- UserName

**Table2 - CategoryList**

- **CategoryID (PK)**
- CategoryName

**Table3 - User_Category**

- UserID (FK) (also PK with CategoryID)
- CategoryID (FK)

Comment: if `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't work, try this, `FIND_IN_SET(b.ID, REPLACE(a.category,' ', ''))`

Answer (score 0):

What so difficult about it? First, query `select category from table1` (say, store result in $res). Then in loop like `while($arr = $res->fetch_row())` retrieve array of categories used for this user in a manner like that `$ids = explode(",",$arr[0])`, and append it in your list of all used is's (like `$all_ids = array_merge($all_ids, $ids)`).

Ok now you have array of all id's used, now with query `select * from table2` and loop `while($row = $res->fetch_row)` just do `if($row[0] not in $all_ids)$free_cats[]=$row[1]`.

I hope you will figure out how to make a string out of this $free_cats array now.